# Passing variable to Linux bash command parameter

Tags: linux, bash, parameters, command

I have the following bash script thowring exception: "cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'".

It would cut out the 5th colunm from /etc/passwd, separated by ':' character.

How should I pass the $variable to the option's parameter?

```
variable=5; cut -d':' -f$variable < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: That line of code works fine for me.

Comment: this should work.  make sure you're on `bash` shell.  `echo $0` will say.  Also same as this `variable=5; cut -d: -f$variable /etc/passwd` with extra chars eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

You get this when `$variable` is empty:

```
$ variable=
$ cut -d: -f$variable </etc/passwd
cut: option requires an argument -- 'f'
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
```

2 suggestions:

1. ensure the variable has a value
2. [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667), and in this case, separate the option from the argument: at least you'll get a saner error when the value is empty

   ```
   $ cut -d : -f "$variable" </etc/passwd
   cut: fields are numbered from 1
   Try 'cut --help' for more information.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that, use

```
set -o nounset
```

and then, if `variable` is unset you'll receive

```
bash: variable: unbound variable
```